# Exclude patterns for Doxygen when started via Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, doxygen

I have set up a Doxyfile with some exclude patterns. Now that I let the documentation run in Jenkins Pipeline via bat, the exclude patterns do not apply.
However, when I start Doxygen with a Windows Script in a Jenkins Freestyle Project, the exclude patterns work properly. 
How does Doxygen exclude specific folders properly, when I start it in Jenkins Pipeline? I use the old scripted format.

I already tried to let it run on an agent, however, it was the same result.
I tried to run in natively in Windows on the Jenkins Master, where the exclude patterns worked correctly.
I tried every string format for pipeline (', ", '''). But the result was always wrong.

Edit: 
I moved the exclusions from EXCLUDE_PATTERN to EXCLUDE. However, it had the same strange behaviour.
/Edit

here is the part of the pipeline script that starts Doxygen:

```
bat script: 'doxygen projects_settings/doxygen/Doxyfile'
publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: false, reportDir: '\\documentation\\html\\', reportFiles: 'index.html', reportName: 'Doxygen Documentation', reportTitles: ''])
```

Edit2: now I am really confused. I let doxygen install via custom tool plugin and it had the same behaviour. However, as I moved the configuration to another Jenkins server/instance, it worked correctly. There must be something wrong on my jenkins installation...

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What is the content of the Doxyfile. What are the starting directories in case of the "pipeline" and the "Freestyle project Windows Script"?

Comment: I use doxygen 1.8.15 on a windows server 2016 machine. The Doxyfile contains a lot since it was created with doxywizard. However this is the cucial part: `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = */os/* */hw_drivers/*` . The Folders in both projects are the same. It starts on the upper project folder as it is provided via GIT.

Comment: I still haven't found out, why I had this behaviour. My solution was to use the other Jenkins instance (glad we had two...). I am however no longer working on this error.